# How to remove a specific character from all the rows in one column of a dataframe

Tags: r, regex, subset, gsub, grepl

I have a dataframe with two columns and a few hundred rows, let's call it `df` which looks like this -

```
Name                 Chemical_Formula
PALMITYL-COA         C37H62N7O17P3S1
CPD0-888             C34H52N7O24P2
3-OXOPALMITOYL-COA   C37H60N7O18P3S1
OH-MYRISTOYL         C43H75N3O20P2
CPD-19171            C39H64N7O18P3S1
CPD-15253            C52H99N3O13P2
CPD-12122            C75H112O2
CPD0-937             C149H260N2O78P4
....                 .....
....                 .....
```

Now if the `Chemical_Formula` for some of the compounds ends in `1` I want to remove that `1` from the chemical formula. For example for the first compound `PALMITYL-COA` the chemical formula is `C37H62N7O17P3S1` which ends in `1`. So in my new dataframe I want the chemical formula for this first compound to be `C37H62N7O17P3S`.

So, my new dataframe should look like this -

```
Name                 Chemical_Formula
PALMITYL-COA         C37H62N7O17P3S
CPD0-888             C34H52N7O24P2
3-OXOPALMITOYL-COA   C37H60N7O18P3S
OH-MYRISTOYL         C43H75N3O20P2
CPD-19171            C39H64N7O18P3S
CPD-15253            C52H99N3O13P2
CPD-12122            C75H112O2
CPD0-937             C149H260N2O78P4
....                 .....
....                 .....
```

I want to keep all the Chemical Formulas as it is if they don't end in the number `1`. The ones which end in `1` I just want to remove that 1, keeping the rest of the formula as it is.

I was looking for ways to do this using `gsub sub grepl`or`subset` functions but not quite sure what pattern to give using the regular expression rules. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how

```
df$Chemical_Formula <- gsub("1$", "", df$Chemical_Formula)
```

The dollar sign after the 1 means end of a string. Meaning it will only remove a 1 if it is located at the end

Comment: it seems you both did at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Following may help you here. Where I am using `sub` substitute function of base `R` to remove `1` if it id at end of the element with NULL.

```
sub("1$","",df$Chemical_Formula)
```

To save this output into same column use `df$Chemical_Formula <-` in above code too.

***Explanation of code:***

`sub`: `sub` is base `R`'s function which works on method of `sub(regex_needs_to_be_used_to_replace_present_content,"with_new_content",variable)`

`"1$"`: Means telling `sub` to act upon only those line which are ending with `1` for df's column named `Chemical_Formula`(which I am explaining further this post)

`""`: If above match found in any value then replace line's ending `1` with NULL here as per OP's request.

`df$Chemical_Formula`: data frame named df's column named `Chemical_Formula`